# Django interface buttons no longer work after connecting to IP 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: python, django, connection, ip

I am trying to access Django website from a secondary device using

```py
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The primary device that my laptop is connected to the same network as my secondary device, and I have turned off all firewalls. Also, I have configured the Allowed Host in settings.py file in Django by adding the IP address of the common connected data (`192.168.61.130`). However, when I access the website, the buttons on the website does not direct me to any page that I have linked in urls.py file.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.61.130', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

From the example below, I have pressed the log in button and the POST request does show on the terminal. However, it does not direct me to the next page when I connect to the IP: `0.0.0.0:8000`.

The website works completely fine when I run on local host.
Not sure why this is so and really need help on this. Hope to get any advice.

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you set allowed hosts to `*`?

Comment: Have tried that. It does not work as well.

Comment: So you only have that problem while doing POST requests, right? I think it is not a matter of allowed hosts, but of the CSRF verification. Check out [CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins) and all the other settings with CSRF. It might have something to do with that.

Comment: Yes, the problem only exists when doing POST requests. If I wish to enable all POST requests in the script to be accepted, what do I have to input in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS? Examples stated to input url but my Django project is now hosted locally.

Comment: I have added the following to my settings.py file in my Django project but it still can't seem to work:   CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://0.0.0.0",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://192.168.61.130",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
]